# I need to get a value of specific object's property, but don't know the type of the object

Tags: c#, reflection

I have got an c# object and I don't know the type of this object. (i.e. object o)
What I know is that this object has a member called 'ID' of type int.

I wanted to get the value of this property but I am not good enough with reflection...

I can get a type and members of this object:

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] member = type.GetMember("ID");
```

...but don't know what to do next :-)

Thanks for help in advance
Mariusz

Comment: If you're using c# 4.0 then dynamics would work like everyone else has suggested. But when you say that you don't know the type of object, are you saying that you will never ever know the type of object or that you just don't know how to determine what type is stored in an object variable?  Edit:  Do you at least know the possible types that the obj variable will contain?  Personally, I wouldn't use dynamics if you know the possible types.  In that case, I'd use `if/else if` logic instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for all answers. I am shocked how helpful you all guys are !!! 
I have got few excellent answers.
The one John provided: int value = (int)property.GetValue(obj, null);
It was what I was looking for initially It works very well. Thanks again John.
I have to mention that I have been thrown on my knees what seen Jared’s suggestion using dynamic.
It is just beautiful and simple.
Thanks again.

Comment: oscilatingcretin - the object may be of different type every time I get my hands on it. I just know that it has two peoperties: ID int and Name string and I was interested with the first one.

I can use dynamics and it looks as a cleanest solution.

Comment: I think a lot of .NET gurus will have slight seizures over the use of reflection for something like this. If you're looking for that style of functionality, definitely go for dynamics. However, I'm still curious if the type truly is completely unknown. It seems hard to believe that you'd be passing a ghastly random number of different objects through to one method.  Ok nevermind you posted yours at the same time I posted mine

Comment: ok, let me explain then. I use ListBox control within a win-forms app. I get an array of IEnumerable objects and bind them to the control using DisplayMember, ValueMember and DataSource properties. DisplayMember and ValueMamber are always this same (ID int and Name string) but the whole object differs based on what query (EF 4.0 with repositories providing CRUD) has been used (or more precise, which table within a database the query was executed against). UI and business logic are within different layers. Business layer doesn't know who will consume results and vice versa.

Hope this clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a public property?  Is so then the easiest route is to use `dynamic`

```
int value = ((dynamic)obj).ID;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("ID");
int id = (int) property.GetValue(obj, null);
```

- Use `PropertyInfo` because you know it's a property, which makes things easier
- Call [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue.aspx) to get the value, passing in `obj` as the target of the property and `null` for indexer arguments (as it's a property, not an index)
- Cast the result to `int` as you already know it's going to be an `int`

Jared's suggestion of using `dynamic` is good too, if you're using C# 4 and .NET 4, although to avoid all the brackets I'd probably write it as:

```
dynamic d = obj;
int id = d.ID;
```

(unless you needed it in a single expression for some reason).

Comment: I remember you mentioning on one of the podcasts (it probably was .Net Rocks) that happens that people make your answer accepted because you are the JS :-)

I was tempted as well I have to say because your answer is awesome... as always :-) but I hope you won't mind that this time driss'es dynamic beauty will be the one.

Thanks
Mariusz

Comment: @Mariusz: Not a problem - although Jared posted the dynamic approach first :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you use C# 4 ? In that case, you can use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic dyn = obj;
int id = dyn.ID;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use var for `dyn.ID`. since its dynamic it will just resolve into `object`. you should use a specific type (`int` as the OP said) or dynamic as well.

Comment: And again, beautiful solution using dynamic. Thanks driis.
It seems worth to start learning F# or some functional language. If everything is so cool within functional world I don't know what I  am still doing here
 :-)

Comment: @sllev: when you put any dynamic object or object you got from dynamic object into var, the var behaves as it was `object`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {
        // defaults
        this.IdField = 1;
        this.IdProperty = 2;
    }

    public int IdField;
    public int IdProperty { get; set; }
}

// here is an object obj and you don't know which its underlying type
object obj = new TestClass();
var idProperty = obj.GetType().GetProperty("IdProperty");
if (idProperty != null)
{
    // retrieve it and then parse to int using int.TryParse()
    var intValue = idProperty.GetValue(obj, null);
}

var idField = obj.GetType().GetField("IdField");
if (idField != null)
{
    // retrieve it and then parse to int using int.TryParse()
    var intValue = idField.GetValue(obj);
}
```